# minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:flutter_blue]

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

When I try to run my flutter app on android device from android studio I'm getting this error: minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:flutter_blue], I know what I have to do is add:

```
defaultConfig {
minSdkVersion 19
}
```

I added this line in the build.gradle file but I'm still getting the same error, also I have in my pubspec.yaml my dependencie like this:

```
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
flutter_blue: ^0.8.0
```

this is my flutter version:

```
Flutter 3.7.10 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 4b12645012 (11 days ago) • 2023-04-03 17:46:48 -0700
Engine • revision ec975089ac
Tools • Dart 2.19.6 • DevTools 2.20.1
```

Dart sdk version: Dart SDK version: `2.19.6 (stable) (Tue Mar 28 13:41:04 2023 +0000) on "windows_x64"`.
When I run the flutter doctor command everything is ok.

I don't know if I'm missing something, also I created the issue in https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue directly.To take into account: I can run the same app on iPhone without problems from visual studio code

Answer (score 1):

In file
*project_folder/android/local.properties*
write

```
flutter.minSdkVersion=19
```

And then in file
*project_folder/android/app/build.gradle*
write

```
minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()
```

https://www.flutterbeads.com/change-android-minsdkversion-in-flutter/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have updated correct build.gradle file, it should be in the app directory. Example for how this should look like:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 32 // could be also 30 etc.
    }
}
```

If that is correct you may refresh flutter dependencies:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Comment: I had done that but neither works, I get this error now: 
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
  or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
  or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.pauldemarco.flutter_blue" to force usage 
    (may lead to runtime failures)

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
    > Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Comment: this project looks ok, its minSdk is 19, I think the problem is with some artefacts on your side. You may need to do some deep cache cleaning. Like android studio full cache clean, then clean your project, then maybe delete ~/.gradle folder

Comment: recently I found my error, I put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was in the build.gradle file,I had the default config like this:

```
 defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    applicationId "com.example.myApp"
    minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion //I had to delete this line
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

after the line minSdkVersion 19 I had another line minSdkVersion with this value flutter.minSdkVersion,I didn´t know that this value is set up on my pubspec.yaml in the flutter section, like this:

```
flutter:
minSdkVersion: 21
```

if we don't have this value flutter takes the default min value that is 16, so you can put this value on the pubSpec.yaml or you can delete the second line on the build.gradle file